# JavaFX progress bar component activated from Spring Listener Method

Tags: spring, user-interface, javafx

I have three layer(gui->services->dao) desktop application (JavaFX+Spring 4). 
Some of my methods realized in my services layer (without fx dependency) have long time computing. I'd like to report their progress in gui.

But there is a problem. My service layer hasn't got direct access to gui, make a log of IO operations and returns only summarize of it. GUI layer, doesn't know about progress of intermediate operations.

I try to make a generic progress component. It could be realized as a Spring Bean with listener method located id GUI layer. My services can publish `ApplicationEvent`, which can be received via progress component in gui. When it gets the event, should activate progress bar and report next events.

In init methods I have started `ProgressTask`, and bind `progressProperty` with my gui progress bar control.

Call method of my `ProgressTask` runs while actual counter is less that max number of steps.

There is my component:

```
@Component
@Controller
public class ProgressBarComponent  {

    @FXML
    private ProgressBar progressBar;



    private ProgressTask actTask;

    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
    }

    private void initProgressBar(int aMax){
        actTask=new ProgressTask();
        actTask.initState(aMax);
        progressBar.progressProperty().bind(actTask.progressProperty());
    new Thread(actTask).start();
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleProgressEvent(ProgressEvent event) {
        if(event.getGetActStep()==0){
            initProgressBar(event.getMaxStep());
        }
        actTask.changeState(event.getGetActStep());
    }


    class ProgressTask extends Task<Object>{
        private int max=100;
        private int act=0;
        private volatile boolean cancelled;

        public void initState(int aMax){
            this.max=aMax;
        }

        public void changeState(int newVal){
            act=newVal;
            updateProgress(act, max);
            updateMessage("progress: " + act);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Object call() throws Exception {
            while(act<max){
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

But it doesn't work. 
Progress bar control is activated but in one step and at once it has a 100 percent value.

I have found a lot of examples Progress Bar FX control, but all of them assume that main logic is computed inside `call()` method of `ProgressTask`. In my case it isn't possible.

It is possible to make a `ProgressBar` Component, which is activated from listener method ? If yes, what code should be in `ProgressTask.call()` method ?

Comment: I might not know enough about Spring events to understand how this is supposed to work, but what is `ProgressEvent`, and how is your service invoking this? The entire purpose of a `Task` is to do the background work, so if that is being done elsewhere, it's not really clear what the point of the `Task` implementation is at all. At a very minimum, though, `max` and `act` should be `volatile`, as they are being written in one thread and read from another; and your busy-wait loop in the `call()` method is not a good idea at all.

Comment: And presumably the actual work is being performed on a background thread, and not on the FX Application Thread...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of a `Task` is to define some functionality that should be run on a background thread. So if this functionality is already implemented elsewhere, there is no need for a task.

Assuming the service is being invoked on a background thread (i.e. not on the FX Application Thread), you should just be able to do:

```
@Component
@Controller
public class ProgressBarComponent  {

    private int max ;

    @FXML
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
    }

    private void initProgressBar(int aMax){
        this.max = aMax ;
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleProgressEvent(ProgressEvent event) {
        if(event.getGetActStep()==0){
            Platform.runLater(() -> initProgressBar(event.getMaxStep()));
        }
        Platform.runLater(() -> 
            progressBar.setProgress(1.0 * event.getGetActStep() / max));
    }
}
```

Here's a complete SSCCE:

ProgressViewer.java:

```
package springevent;

import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ProgressViewer {

    private Stage stage = new Stage();
    private Scene scene ;
    private ProgressBar progressBar ;

    public ProgressViewer() {
        progressBar = new ProgressBar();
        StackPane root = new StackPane(progressBar);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
    }

    @EventListener
    public void progressUpdate(ProgressEvent event) {
        if (event.getCurrent() < event.getMax()) {
            Platform.runLater(stage::show);
        } else {
            Platform.runLater(stage::hide);
        }
        final double progress = 1.0 * event.getCurrent() / event.getMax() ;
        Platform.runLater(() -> progressBar.setProgress(progress));
    }
}
```

Service.java:

```
package springevent;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

public class Service {

    @Inject
    private ApplicationContext context ;

    public void runService() {
        context.publishEvent(new ProgressEvent(0, 100));
        try {
            for (int i = 1 ; i <= 100; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(200);
                context.publishEvent(new ProgressEvent(i, 100));
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

ProgressEvent.java

```
package springevent;

public class ProgressEvent {

    private final int current ;
    private final int max ;

    public ProgressEvent(int current, int max) {
        this.current = current ;
        this.max = max ;
    }

    public int getCurrent() {
        return current ;
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return max ;
    }
}
```

MainController.java

```
package springevent;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class MainController {

    @Inject
    private Executor exec ;

    @Inject
    private Service service ;

    @FXML
    private Button startButton ;

    public void startProcess() {
        exec.execute(service::runService);
    }

    @EventListener
    public void progressUpdate(ProgressEvent event) {
        startButton.setDisable(event.getCurrent() < event.getMax());
    }

}
```

Main.fxml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>

<StackPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="springevent.MainController">
    <padding>
        <Insets top="20" bottom="20" left="20" right="20"/>
    </padding>
    <Button fx:id="startButton" text="Start process" onAction="#startProcess" />
</StackPane>
```

Main.java

```
package springevent;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private AbstractApplicationContext context ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
        loader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);
        Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and AppConfig.java:

```
package springevent;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public Service service() {
        return new Service();
    }

    @Bean
    public MainController mainController() {
        return new MainController();
    }

    @Bean
    public ProgressViewer progressViewer() {
        return new ProgressViewer();
    }

    @Bean
    public Executor exec() {
        return Executors.newCachedThreadPool(runnable -> {
            Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t ;
        });
    }
}
```